# How does the temperature of a magnet affect its characteristics?

Tags: electromagnetism, temperature

How does the temperature of a magnet affect its characteristics? Is a hot or cold magnet stronger? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort. There are dozens of articles on this phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

Heating the magnet will cause the magnet to have a weaker magnetic field. Cooling the magnet will cause the magnet to have a stronger magnetic field.

Why?

An important part of the relationship between magnets and temperature is the fact that heating the magnet causes its molecules to become more disorderly. Magnets are dipoles, which means they have an opposite charge, or magnetic direction, at each end. This is a result of most of the magnetic molecules facing the same direction. When we heat our magnets, those polar molecules start moving around. The average direction of the entire magnet’s polarity becomes a little bit messier because those magnetic molecules are no longer facing the same direction.

If magnets are heated to the Curie point, they lose their ability to be magnetic. The dipoles become so disordered that they can’t return to their original state.